# Subselect e concatenar o resultado mesma coluna Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com essa query, sem o `subselect` ela me retorna:

```
Cod_atendimento | cod_agrupamento| cod_material
11223.             2.              200
11223.             2.              300
```

Resultado que eu to tentando:

```
Cod_atendimento | cod_agrupamento| cod_material
11223.             2.              200, 300
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cod_atendimento,
COD_AGRUPAMENTO,
COALESCE(
(SELECT CAST(cd.cod_material AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' AS [text()]
FROM 
PRESCRICAO_MEDICA_V ab, PRESCRICAO_SOLUCAO bc, PRESCRICAO_MATERIAL cd
where ab.cod_prescricao = bc.cod_prescricao
and bc.cod_prescricao = cd.cod_prescricao
and ab.cod_prescricao = 23214
and cod.ie_suspenso = 'N'
AND cd.COD_SEQUENCIA_SOLUCAO = bc.COD_SEQ_SOLUCAO
ORDER BY CODIGO
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') as materiais

from 
PRESCRICAO_MEDICA_V a, 
PRESCRICAO_SOLUCAO b, 
PRESCRICAO_MATERIAL c
where a.cod_prescricao = b.cod_prescricao
and b.cod_prescricao = c.cod_prescricao
and a.cod_prescricao = 23214
AND c.COD_SEQUENCIA_SOLUCAO = b.COD_SEQ_SOLUCAO
GROUP BY a.cod_atendimento, b.COD_AGRUPAMENTO
```

Comment: Tente com listagg https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro algo assim:

Sugiro também adoptar o uso da sintaxe ANSI para os `JOINS` que, para além de ser comum à generalidade das implementações de SQL, torna a leitura mais fácil (e não traz implicações à performance).

```
SELECT 
  cod_atendimento,
  cod_agrupamente
  LISTAGG(materiais, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY materiais) AS materiais
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    cod_atendimento,
    cod_agrupamente,
    COALESCE((SELECT CAST(cd.cod_material AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' AS [text()]
              FROM prescricao_medica_v ab, prescricao_solucao bc, prescricao_material cd
              WHERE ab.cod_prescricao = bc.cod_prescricao
                AND bc.cod_prescricao = cd.cod_prescricao
                AND ab.cod_prescricao = 23214
                AND cod.ie_suspenso = 'N'
                AND cd.cod_sequencia_solucao = bc.cod_seq_solucao
              ORDER BY CODIGO
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), ''), '; ')
    ) as materiais
  FROM prescricao_medica_v a, prescricao_solucao b, prescricao_material c
  WHERE a.cod_prescricao = b.cod_prescricao
    AND b.cod_prescricao = c.cod_prescricao
    AND a.cod_prescricao = 23214
    AND c.cod_sequencia_solucao = b.cod_seq_solucao
)
GROUP BY cod_atendimento, cod_agrupamento;
```

Comment: E o perguntador some....